# ListView showing shuffled images after scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an application in which I am showing ListView with two different layouts. I have about 25 items in a list and initial items shows in well order with everything as I want but when I scroll down some items in particular row overrides each other and every time I scroll they show up in different manner than the previous one. Images also gets shuffled and overrides each other.

> This is my Custom Adapter class :-

```
public class CustomAdapterSettings extends BaseAdapter {

private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

private ArrayList<String> arrListData = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrListDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater layInflater;
private Context context;
private TreeSet<Integer> treeSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

public CustomAdapterSettings(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    layInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void addItem(final String data, final String description) {
    arrListData.add(data);
    arrListDescription.add(description);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(final String seperator) {
    arrListData.add(seperator);
    arrListDescription.add(seperator);
    // save separator position
    treeSeparatorsSet.add(arrListData.size() - 1);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return treeSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR
            : TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrListData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return arrListData.get(position);
}

public String getItemDescription(int position) {
    return arrListDescription.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvSettingsTagSeper;
    public TextView tvSettingsDescription;
    public CheckBox cbSettings;
    public ImageView ivSettings;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    int type;
    type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView
            + " type = " + type);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_ITEM:

            convertView = layInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_settings_list, null);
            viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvSettingsTag);
            viewHolder.tvSettingsDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvSettingsDescription);
            viewHolder.cbSettings = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cbSettings);
            viewHolder.ivSettings = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivSettings);
            break;
        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            convertView = layInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_seperator,
                    null);
            viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvSeperator);
            break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (type == 0) {
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setTextSize(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.heightScreen * 0.035));
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setPadding(0,
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.heightScreen * 0.01),
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.15), 0);
        viewHolder.tvSettingsDescription.setPadding(0,
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.heightScreen * 0.001),
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.15), 0);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.ivSettings
                .getLayoutParams();
        layParams.setMargins(0, 0,
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.045), 0);
        viewHolder.ivSettings.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.heightScreen * 0.06);

        viewHolder.ivSettings.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.heightScreen * 0.06);

        viewHolder.ivSettings.setLayoutParams(layParams);
        layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.cbSettings
                .getLayoutParams();
        layParams.setMargins(0, 0,
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.03), 0);
        viewHolder.cbSettings.setLayoutParams(layParams);
        layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper
                .getLayoutParams();
        layParams.setMargins(
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.05), 0, 0,
                0);
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setLayoutParams(layParams);
        layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.tvSettingsDescription
                .getLayoutParams();
        layParams.setMargins(
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.05), 0, 0,
                0);
        viewHolder.tvSettingsDescription.setLayoutParams(layParams);

    } else {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper
                .getLayoutParams();
        layParams.setMargins(
                (int) (ScreenCalculationActivity.widthScreen * 0.02), 0, 0,
                0);
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setLayoutParams(layParams);
    }
    if (type == 0) {
        if (position == 1 || position == 2 || position == 3
                || position == 6 || position == 9 || position == 10
                || position == 12 || position == 14 || position == 16
                || position == 18 || position == 22) {
            viewHolder.ivSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.cbSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        viewHolder.cbSettings.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.cbSettings.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        viewHolder.ivSettings.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.ivSettings.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        if (arrListDescription.get(position) == null) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setLayoutParams(layParams);
        }
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setText(arrListData.get(position));
        viewHolder.tvSettingsDescription.setText(arrListDescription
                .get(position));
    } else {
        viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setText(arrListData.get(position));
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

> This is my layout layout_settings_list :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relLaySettings"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSettingsTag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSettingsDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSettingsTag"
    android:textColor="@color/LightGrey" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivSettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/dropdown2"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

> This is my layout layout_seperator :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/LightGrey"
android:clickable="false">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSeperator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason to hard code the different positions where you want special behavior? Why isn't this a field of your backing objects? I'm talking about the big `if` with a lot of `position == ...`

Comment: I am inflating two layouts based on the position number so I want different behaviour for different rows..

Comment: Obviously, but why isn't it coded in backing objects instead of specific positions? It does not make sense to me since you seem to create your list dynamically via `addItem` and `addSeparatorItem`. The type should be a property of the items you add.

Comment: What do u mean by backing objects??

Comment: Also, in this very `if` you set one element to `VISIBLE` but you don't seem to set the other to `GONE`. Once the view is recycled, you might have both the `ivSettings` and the `cbSettings` visible.

Comment: By backing objects, I mean the objects in your `ArrayList`s. Actually, there should be only one list, with more complex objects than Strings. Those objects would contain both the data and the desciption, or they would be separators, maybe these 2 types inheriting from the same parent class. And thoses objects could contain the property you need to determine whether to display `ivSettings` or `cbSettings`

Comment: Ok, I got it...but do u think that this is creating the problem of shuffling?

Comment: I think the fact that you keep one or the other view visible while you think it is not makes you think items are shuffled. You're probably seeing views that you shouldn't see in addition to views that you properly set. I'm writing an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the exact source of your problem, but I see several little issues that might cause what you see.

### Several backing lists

The purpose of your adapter is to convert a list of objects into a list a views in the screen. Having multiple lists containing the data does not seem right to me. It shouldn't cause actual problems, but it could make your mental representation harder.

You should probably have objects encapsulating the properties you will reflect in your views:

```
public class Item {
}

public class DataItem extends Item {
    String data;
    String description;
}

public class SeparatorItem extends Item {
    String description;
}
```

And instead of 2 lists and 1 set, you would only have one list:

```
ArrayList<Item> list;
```

Then you could base your item type on the actual class of the item (instead of using a Set of indices):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Item item = list.get(position);
    if (item instanceof DataItem)
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    else 
        return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
}
```

### Suspicious `if` statement

```
if (position == 1 || position == 2 || position == 3
      || position == 6 || position == 9 || position == 10
      || position == 12 || position == 14 || position == 16
      || position == 18 || position == 22) {
    viewHolder.ivSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    viewHolder.cbSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Two problems with this `if`:

- it hardcodes some positions. There should be a field in your backing objects (the `Item`s of your list) that represents the fact that `ivSettings` or `cbSettings` (one view or the other) should be displayed.
- you use `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`, but where do you set the other view to `View.GONE`? They are not initialized, so the visibility of `ivSettings` or `cbSettings` (the one you don't make visible) will be the one of your `convertView`.

Suggested corrected `if`:

```
Item item = list.get(position);
if (item.shouldDisplayIvSettings()) {
    viewHolder.ivSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewHolder.cbSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    viewHolder.ivSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.cbSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

### Constants declarations VS use of integer literals

You had it right when you declared constants for your types of elements:

```
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
```

But then you don't use the constants, but integer literals in your `if`s:

```
if (type == 0) {
```

This is not much, but could cause errors when your code evolves. It should be replaced by the appropriate constant:

```
if (type == TYPE_ITEM) {
```

Comment: @Vikalp Ok, no problem. Feel free to edit your question if you have more info then ;-)

Comment: As you told me about visibility of ivSettings and cbSettings, I have changed that and now the images are not getting shuffled but the texts are still overriding each other and I found the source of problem but can't find a solution

Comment: if (arrListDescription.get(position) == null) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            viewHolder.tvSettingsTagSeper.setLayoutParams(layParams);
        } These lines in my getview() method are creating problems. I think when I set TextView to center_vertical then next time getview() is called with same alignment that is center_vertical. I tried to change it to align_parent_top but it didn't work..

Comment: @Vikalp Why is this a problem? Don't you want the alignment to stay the same?

Comment: I have got two text views and one image view in my one row layout of listview. I am changing the alignment only when one text view got null value so that the other one appears in middle of one row